# PHP Relative Include with Virtual Directory on IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7, relative-path

I have a root configuration virtual directory (named "config" pointing to a directory inside /wwwroot/) specified in IIS7. I want to access this virtual dir programmatically via an "include" function such as:

`include '/config/main.php';`

I get `Warning: require(config/main.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream` errors. I have tried the following:

`/config/`, `\config\`, `./config/`, `config/`, `~/config/`, `$SERVER_['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/config/`

To no avail. Why does PHP have to be such a dink about site relative references!? Not to rain on the parade, but ASP can handle site relative references (or document relative with `../blah.php`) with ease!

Any ideas? I have looked at the set_include_path function and I'm going to try that out in the meantime, but it basically seems like that would be hard-coding my directory paths - annoying for moving code from dev to prod environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is sort of closed because I couldn't find a satisfactory answer, I simply just rejigged my problem so that there's no virtual directories. Damn PHP and relative paths! It seems to be  a problem specifically with IIS.

If anyone finds a better solution the problem I will be more than happy to switch the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
dirname(__FILE__).'\\config\\main.php';
```

Comment: No that didn't work. If it were in the same directory it might ... but this is a virtual directory outside of the main site.